# Best way to distribute node_modules folder in NW.js build?

Tags: nwjs

I'm currently copying my node_modules folder into my final (Mac) app. This avoids the need to run `npm install` on the user's computer—it works out of the box. However, node_modules is a huge folder (400mb+), so it would be better to distribute something smaller.

1. Is there a way (for an NW.JS app) to distribute/package the node_modules folder at a smaller size? (i.e. only the dist files for each module, compressed, etc.)
2. Would this be a good use-case for WebPack?

Comment: Look up package.lock - if you check that into your repo you can ensure other users get the same node_modules tree as you. Checking in node_modules is unnecessary.

Comment: @ChrisCousins The problem isn't having the same versions. It's more about how to best deliver the node_modules for an NW.JS Mac app specifically. Since it's an app, users shouldn't need to download Node and run `npm install` before they can use it. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Ah yes then using a bundled like webpack will reduce your deliverable to a single js file (if you don’t use chunks)

Comment: Try creating a dmg or pkg to deliver the app. It will package all contents with compression.

Answer (score 0):

Have you using npm cmd `npm-prune` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune.html

For example run `npm prune --production` will delete all `devDedepndencies` according to your `package.json`. It is very useful to reduce the size of `node_modules` folder. Also you could create you own script to distribute your package.

Here is how I distribute my package:

1. copy NW.js binaries client to `dist` folder
2. copy my working source project into a folder named `package.nw`(Windows) or `app.nw` in `nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/`(MacOS)
3. run `npm prune --production` under the path you just copy your source into.
4. using npm package `plist`(for MacOS) or `rcedit`(for Windows) to change the binaries client's information about version, nanme, author ..etc

For mac these is alot of things needs to be changed if you want to publish to appstore http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Support%20for%20Mac%20App%20Store/